# How to avoid a circular reference with VBA in this case?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm entering many rows of data. Sometimes I'll enter net in column A, and sometimes I'll gross in column C. Net + VAT = Gross. In all cases I want the formulas to calculate the missing numbers for me automatically.

I have three columns (ABC)
column A represents Net, B represents nominal VAT, and C Gross.
I have a formula in B that if A VAT, or if B VAT else blank.

Currently, if I put anything in A, the VAT is calculated and C is blank:

```
  A    B    C
  100  20
```

And equally, if I put anything in C, the VAT is calcualted but A is blank:

```
A    B    C
    20    120
```

What I want is below, whether it is A that is given, or C.

```
A    B    C
100  20   120
```

I am trying to Calculate Net given gross figure, and gross given net figure on a single row.

Note, column B is protected, I have a formula that calculates the VAT automatically whether a figure is entered into C first, or A first:

```
=IF(E2>0,E2*VATRATE,IF(G2>0,G2-(G2/(1+VATRATE)),""))
```

Ideally with VBA, if A given then cal C, and if C given calc A.

Comment: This is actually an excellent question; and a hard one too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need VBA at all for this. Use these formulas:

- Net in A2 `=IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(C2)),C2-B2,0)`
- VAT in B2
  `=IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(A2)),A2*VATRATE,IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(C2)),C2-(C2/(1+VATRATE)),0))`
- Gross in C2 `=A2+B2`

The trick is to determine whether a number was manually entered. Once you know that, you can use if statements to avoid a circular reference.

Copy down for as many lines as you need.

Comment: Just a note for readers: 2013 onwards for Isformula. Alternatives https://superuser.com/questions/360369/how-to-tell-if-an-excel-cell-has-a-formula-or-is-hardcoded