# Populate 1 of 2 cells given data in either

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to populate cells in Excel 2019 based on the value in the other cell without creating a circular reference. I simply want to put a value in cell A1 that includes VAT at 10% then cell B1 will automatically populate Net of the VAT. Likewise if I have the net Value, I want to put it in B2 and have the gross amount automatically populate in B1?
Formula keeps giving me errors and I know nothing about VBA. Seems a fairly simple problem but can't solve it and am now v. frustrated.
Sorry if I seem simple still learning and couldn't find an answer on Google after 2 hrs of searching.
Thanks.

[Image of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow3DB.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some sample data or a screenshot so it has a [reprex], thanks.

Comment: Formula are not going to work as you have seen you are getting circular references.  You will need vba in a worksheet change event that does the calculations behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - yes I am aware that formulas weren't working. The problem is self explanatory so I can't provide any code that isn't working plus I wouldn't know where to start but will google " a worksheet change" Thank you.

Comment: Have read up on worksheet change but there are only basic examples eg counting number of changes in column 1 in cell B2 or highlighting a cell red when it's value has changed - cant find examples of calculations applied to cell B1 based on data put into A1 or visa versa. Thought this would be simple and that many would have already found a solution to this. It is taking too much time so I will just do it manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was found on this site after much searching - credit to D_Bester - Thank you.
Link to post is here :
[How to avoid a circular reference with VBA in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214039/how-to-avoid-a-circular-reference-with-vba-in-this-case?rq=1)

Copy of answer is below - tested and works!

Actually you don't need VBA at all for this. Use these formulas:

```
Net in A2 =IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(C2)),C2-B2,0)
VAT in B2 =IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(A2)),A2*VATRATE,IF(NOT(ISFORMULA(C2)),C2-(C2/(1+VATRATE)),0))
Gross in C2 =A2+B2
```

The trick is to determine whether a number was manually entered. Once you know that, you can use if statements to avoid a circular reference.

Copy down for as many lines as you need.

edited Mar 10 '18 at 22:14
answered Mar 10 '18 at 22:04
D_Bester
4,63744 gold badges2828 silver badges67